# Disable a JavaScript element depending on index of element in a list

Tags: javascript

I want to add code so that when my "pause" function is enabled. The HTML has 10 images that it cycles through. If the image is on index 0, the previous button should be disabled. On index 10, the next button is disabled.

My idea is to add conditionals to the "pause" function which checks the index of the images and disables them respectively, but this has not worked consistently.

```
    var $ = function (id) { 
    return document.getElementById(id); 
};

var imageCache = [];
var imageCounter = 0;
var timer;

var runSlideShow = function() {
    imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
    var image = imageCache[imageCounter];
    $("image").src = image.src;
    $("caption").firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
};

window.onload = function () {
    var listNode = $("image_list");    // the ul element
    var links = listNode.getElementsByTagName("a");

    // Preload image, copy title properties, and store in array
    var i, link, image;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
        link = links[i];
        image = new Image();
        image.src = link.getAttribute("href");
        image.title = link.getAttribute("title");
        imageCache[imageCache.length] = image;
    }

    //start the timer and disable start
    $("start").onclick = function() {
        runSlideShow();
        timer = setInterval(runSlideShow, 2000);
        $("start").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        //Disable previous and next
        $("previous").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        $("next").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        $("pause").removeAttribute("disabled"); 
    };

    //Stop the time and disable pause
    $("pause").onclick = function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $("start").removeAttribute("disabled");
        //enable previous and next
        $("previous").removeAttribute("disabled");
        $("next").removeAttribute("disabled");
        $("pause").setAttribute("disabled", "true"); 


    };
    //Previous
    $("previous").onclick = function() {
        imageCounter = (imageCounter - 1) % imageCache.length;
        var image = imageCache[imageCounter];
        $("image").src = image.src;
        $("caption").firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;  

    };
    //Next
    $("next").onclick = function() {
        imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
        var image = imageCache[imageCounter];
        $("image").src = image.src;
        $("caption").firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;  
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make by default `$("previous").setAttribute("disabled", "true");` on load

When you click on 'Next' make previous btn true and in runSlideShow  method check the image counter and according that you can play with btn .
like below

```
  var runSlideShow = function() {
     imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
     if( imageCounter.length  === 0){
        $("previous").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        $("next").setAttribute("disabled", "false");
     } else if(imageCounter.length === imageCache.length){
        $("previous").setAttribute("disabled", "false");
        $("next").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
     } else {
       $("previous").setAttribute("disabled", "false");
       $("next").setAttribute("disabled", "false");
     }
     var image = imageCache[imageCounter];
     $("image").src = image.src;
     $("caption").firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you! FYI, imageCounter already returns an integer, so using imageCounter.length was prooving to be redundant

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my question by adding the following code to my previous and next functions:

```
    //Previous
$("previous").onclick = function() {
    imageCounter = (imageCounter - 1) % imageCache.length;
    var image = imageCache[imageCounter];
    $("image").src = image.src;
    $("caption").firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
    $("next").removeAttribute("disabled");
    if(imageCounter === 0){
        $("previous").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    };  
};
//Next
$("next").onclick = function() {
    imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
    var image = imageCache[imageCounter];
    $("image").src = image.src;
    $("caption").firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
    $("previous").removeAttribute("disabled");
    if(imageCounter === 9){
        $("next").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    };
```